Typo in a custom close reason

Requests for analyzing or decyphering a block of data are off-topic here, as the results are rarely useful to anyone else.

Please correct the spelling of deciphering.
Moderators cannot edit custom close reasons, so this requires staff intervention.

I've seen a lot of people write 'decypher' instead of 'decipher'. I can't help but wonder if it's a rarely-used archaic version or something, although it is in the list of Wikipedia's common misspellings. Along similar lines, I've seen people use 'cypher' instead of 'cipher'. (In fact, as an anecdote, Firefox thinks both cypher and cipher are spelled correctly.)

@Reid Google Ngrams supports decypher as an archaic form of decipher, largely unused since the mid-to-late 19th century.

If you want to find out more about this bug, decipher this:

Svkrq, rawbl synttlat!


Oh great, just lost 13 seconds thinking about that one. ;)
